# Where can I buy a cup of 'cat poo' coffee (Kopi Luwak) in Melbourne?

Tags: australia, melbourne, food-and-drink

I'm currently in Melbourne, a coffee-lover's paradise.  As such, I'm quite keen to try the infamous 'cat poo' coffee ([Kopi Luwak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopi_Luwak)) in Melbourne, given that the skill of a Melbourne barista is likely to surpass mine, and should be able to brew a good cup.

To be clear - I don't want to buy the coffee grains or bags of it, I want to buy a cup of it to drink.

[image]

([from Wikicommons](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Luwak-Katze_in_Kepahiang.jpg))

The excreted deposits from the palm civet, after eating:

[image]

([also from Wikicommons](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Indonesian_farmer_shows_coffee_beans_already_digested_by_Asian_Palm_Civet,_but_before_cleaning_and_roasting.jpg))

Comment: As of 2010 [none existed in Melbourne](http://www.mailintalks.com/2010/02/05/kopi-coffee-luwak/)

Comment: You can buy it from eBay. Or if you're going to Indonesia, you can actually visit the farms where these are grown and taste it. (It's actually nice.)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee The idea is to buy a cup.  There are multiple places in Australia selling bags of it

Comment: FWIW, the man who (supposedly) first imported Kopi Luwak to the west has recently [launched a campaign against it](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2013/sep/13/civet-coffee-cut-the-crap) — apparently, its popularity has given rise to an unregulated farming industry, keeping civets (and other animals) in often cruel and unhygienic conditions.  Supposedly, most Kopi Luwak on the market now comes from such farms, even if it claims to be from wild civets.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that any cafés will have this on the menu to be honest. What you could try doing is purchasing a bag of the beans and then taking it to a good barista and ask them to brew it for you. No guarantees that will work, but it might be worth a try. Particularly if you catch them when they're not too busy.

If you are on a quest to taste some great coffee while in Melbourne, you may be interested in this recent article on [the most expensive cup of coffee in Melbourne](http://www.goodfood.com.au/good-food/drink/melbournes-mostprized-and-pricey-coffees-20130621-2onhr.html) (Jun 21, 2013). Price tag: $30.

Comment: Would a "good barista" include a machine I got from Amazon/walmart?

Comment: No. That's a machine. A barista is a person who knows how to operate that machine.